# Convert int to string in fixed no of characters

Tags: python, string, file, int

I am writing int to a file. if the number is 0, then i want to write it in file as 0000. currently

```
o.write(str(year))
```

writes only 0.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

try this: (the essence is using `zfill` to show the number of zeros you want in the most succinct way)

```
if int(my_number_as_string) == 0:
    print my_number_as_string.zfill(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following function will help you to pad zeros

```
def add_nulls2(int, cnt):
    nulls = str(int)
    for i in range(cnt - len(str(int))):
        nulls = '0' + nulls
    return nulls
```

Output

```
>>> add_nulls2(5,5)
'00005'
>>> add_nulls2(0,5)
'00000'
>>>
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hWv1DXG.png